# Value residue of variable AngularJS android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello everybody I'm new here to stack overflow and also angularjs framework. 
long time reader, first time asker, so I hope to get this right.

Here we go:
I have AngularJS 1.3.13 application for android, using ionic 1.3.22 and cordova 5.4.1, working from win 7, and testing on actual android phone (Samsung S6).
My issue is with one page in my app that I'm using for displaying results.

```js
MyCoolApp.controller('ResultsController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  results = {
    {
      id: '1212',
      name: 'Ranger',
      start: '2017-06-27 16:03:00',
      value: '10'
    },
    {
      id: '1215',
      name: '9lives',
      start: '2017-06-27 11:49:01',
      value: '20'
    },
    {
      id: '1245',
      name: 'TigerLily',
      start: '2017-06-27 16:04:00',
      value: '1000'
    }
  };
  hours = {};

  console.log('Hours');
  console.log(hours);

  angular.forEach(results, function(result) {

    var differece = new Date() - new Date(result.start);

    if (hours[result.id]) {
      hours[result.id].differece += differece;


    } else {
      hours[result.id] = {};
      hours[result.id].differece = differece;
    }

  });

  angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
    hours[result.id].differece = hours[result.id].differece / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    result.value = Math.round(result.value / hours[result.id].differece * 100) / 100;

  });

  $scope.resultsData = [];

  angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
    $scope.resultsData.push(result);
  });

});
```

```html
<ion-view title="Results">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <p>Use this screen to see your results</p>
    <ul class="list card">
      <li class="item" ng-repeat="result in resultsData">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <strong><span class="name" ng-bind-html="result.name"></span></strong>
              <td>
                <span class="number" ng-bind-html="result.value | number : 2" style="padding-left:10px"></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

(this snippet doesn't work, not sure why. Think of it as Pseudo code)

Now, my problem is this: 
When I console.log my **hours** var in the controller I get some actual values. 
My calculations go nuts.
Can anybody explain to me why is this happening?

Thx a lot in advance,
Sara

Answer (score 0):

First of all the result array is wrong, it should be an object array like this.

```
results = [
    {
      id: '1212',
      name: 'Ranger',
      start: '2017-06-27 16:03:00'
    },
    {
      id: '1215',
      name: '9lives',
      start: '2017-06-27 11:49:01'
    },
    {
      id: '1245',
      name: 'TigerLily',
      start: '2017-06-27 16:04:00'
    }
  ];
```

Then in your angular.forEach,

```
  angular.forEach(results, function(result) {

    var differece = new Date() - new Date(result.start);

  });
```

With the code, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the quick response.
When I make Your changes for the array to the code, I still don't have correct value for the hours var (there are still, some kind of leftover values). Have in mind that this doesn't have anything to do with the actual code, but is only  a brief inquiry, because I'm stuck, and do not know what else to google. If it will make your mind at ease, lets say that this code tracks how long my cats are outside, and what do they bring as a present.

Comment: The code executions in javascript is asynchronous. If you want to execute the code in a pattern, it is advised to use proper functions and calling them accordingly instead of writing everything in controller directly.